# Add Class & Remove Class after load success on AJAX with setTimeout

Tags: jquery, ajax, button, hyperlink

Hi i have button called 'Refresh' , when someone click that button , the button will be hidden within 24 hours, im trying to create with AJAX added to 'success' , but it seems not working, here's my code (look at complete process) :

```
//Re listings
    $( 'a.relist-free' ).on( 'click', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $( this );
        var propid = $this.data( 'property' );

        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_url,
            data: {
                action: 'houzez_relist_free',
                propID: propid
            },
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: "JSON",

            beforeSend: function( ) {
                houzez_processing_modal(processing_text);
            },
            success: function( response ) {
                window.location.reload();
            },
            complete: function( ){
                $this.addClass( "hidden" );
                setTimeout($this.removeClass( "hidden" ) ,24000);
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Like said in another answer the page will reloaded so can't work in this way but setTimeout use millisecond. 24000 milliseconds is 24 seconds not hours.

Answer (score 1):

Complete will never be called because "success" will reload the page. 
In Success you should add a Cookie or an entry to localstorage with a timestamp.
At the beginning of your js check if an entry exist or if 24h has passed since creation. Then hide or show the button.